# Why list.contains(null) throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: java, exception, collections, nullpointerexception

I have `List<Long> countriesList` which contains `Long` values which are country ids.

Now I am iterating over some `List<UserRequests>` list by using `streams`.

```
userRequests.stream().
    forEach(userRequest->
    {
        UserData=userRepository.findById(userRequest.getId()); //fine
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(countriesList) && countriesList.contains(userRequest.getCountryId()))//getting NPE here
        {
            //do some operation
        }
    });
```

I tried to debug by evaluating individual statements.
I have made sure `countriesList` have some data
First part `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(countriesList)` is returning `true`.
`userRequest` is also not null but `userRequest.getCountryId()` is null.
And when I evaluated `countriesList.contains(userRequest.getCountryId())`, I am getting `Null pointer exception` here. why not `false` ?
I am confused what wrong am I doing.
Is default `list.contains(null)` behaviour is like that only or is it because I am calling it within `stream()`?

Just for simplification I have created simple list and compared with `null`.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Long> longList = List.of(1L, 2L, 3L);
        System.out.println("Comparing long list with null::" + longList.contains(null));
    }
}
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.indexOf(ImmutableCollections.java:166)
    at java.base/java.util.ImmutableCollections$AbstractImmutableList.contains(ImmutableCollections.java:197)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

But If I do:

```
    List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<>();
    longList.add(1L);
    System.out.println("Comparing long list with null::" + longList.contains(null));
```

Why it is printing `false`? Why no `NullPointerException` here?

Comment: Do you have a more precise stack trace?  How do you know which things are and aren't null?  (This may well be the result of a poor design choice by Java, depending on your version.)

Comment: @louis-wasserman updated question to include the exception stack trace and jdk version I am currently using is  `jdk-14.0.2`.

Comment: Removed the `[java-8]` tag, as JDK 14 clearly is not Java 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why `list.contains(null)` throwing null pointer exception?

Because this is what the specs say can happen.

The specific reasoning for the `List.of(...)` case is as follows:

1. The `List.of` methods are [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) as producing [unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).
2. Unmodifiable lists are [specified](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable) to not permit `null` elements:

   > "They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with `null` elements result in `NullPointerException`."
3. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) for `List.contains` states:

   > "Throws: `NullPointerException` - if the specified element is `null` and this list does not permit `null` elements.

In other words, what you are seeing is *specified* behavior ... and not a result of an incorrect or capricious implementation.

For the case where you are searching `countryList` ... it will depend on the actual `List` implementation class.  But there is a clear expectation in the `List` spec for `contains` that *some* kinds of list may throw an NPE if you try to search for `null`.

<sup>(Whether that is a "poor design choice" or not is a matter of opinion.  But it is moot.  The `List` design choices were made a long time ago and changing them would now would be too disruptive to contemplate.  Besides, I doubt that you would convince the current Java design team that `null` values in collection types are a good idea.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

From the API Documentation of [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

> Some list implementations have restrictions on the elements that they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null elements, and some have restrictions on the types of their elements. Attempting to add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically NullPointerException or ClassCastException. Attempting to query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception, or it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the former behavior and some will exhibit the latter. More generally, attempting an operation on an ineligible element whose completion would not result in the insertion of an ineligible element into the list may throw an exception or it may succeed, at the option of the implementation. Such exceptions are marked as "optional" in the specification for this interface.

> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns `true` if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that Objects.equals(o, e).
>
> Specified by:
>
> contains in interface Collection
>
> Parameters:
>
> o - element whose presence in this list is to be tested
>
> Returns:
>
> true if this list contains the specified element
>
> Throws:
>
> ClassCastException - if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this list (optional)
>
> **NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements (optional)**

It seems that your `countriesList` is of a List type that doesn't accept `null` elements, such as those produced by `List.of` or `List.copyOf`

Answer (score 0):

If You want a nullable list then just use `Arrays.asList` instead. Then `contains(null)` won't throw `NullPointerException`.